# Transform xlsx to CSV

Tags: csv, ksh, xlsx, aix

I need to transform an xlsx file to CSV in AIX. The server doesn't have any command for that and I am not allowed to install anything on it. Also, no Python/Perl library for reading Spreadsheets are installed on the server.

Is there still any work around for doing this?

P.S.: it has to work with what is on the server

Comment: I love the votes down but 0 reasons for it

Comment: no spreadsheet library in perl? what about http://search.cpan.org/~dmow/Spreadsheet-XLSX/lib/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm ?

Comment: @Flying_whale Or https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::XLSX for the latest version.

Comment: @melpomene aren't both v0.15 ?

Comment: @Flying_whale Your link says "*Module Version: 0.13*".

Comment: @Flying_whale nope that one isnt there eider

Comment: @melpomene ho yep, my bad

Comment: @kifli what do you mean by "isn't there" ?

Comment: "*it has to work with what is on the server*" - so you're not allowed to write any code?

Comment: @melpomene I can´t install any thing.

Comment: @kifli **I cannot** in the meaning of **I don't succeed** or in the meaning of **I'm not allowed**

Comment: @Flying_whale it is not an option I don´t have permission and it is not allowed.

Comment: thanks for putting it on hold I know I am not allowed ask questions you made it clear but leave it for people who have the same issue even if it is not allowed because it too uncommon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is no way to do it or at least not an easy one (like a simple script or command).

Maybe by working on that xml files (Nahuel Fouilleul answer) but it will take too much time.

jugging by reception alone of the question it looks like people don´t want to touch this issue even with a stick.

Answer (score 0):

xlsx is an open xml format, [specifications](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000398.shtml) can be found.

Otherwise libraries for perl can be found on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~dmow/Spreadsheet-XLSX-0.13-withoutworldwriteables/lib/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm), sources may help to pick some parts.

To start maybe unzip the .xslx it will give a set of xml files and have a look if data can be retrieved.

Comment: it is set of xml files but there isnt a file with raw data of a sheet. It looks like data base made with xml and what suppose to have the info looks like a master table containing references (because there are only numbers)